# How can I prove that every inner product space is strictly convex normed space?

Tags: convex-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let we have $(X,\langle,\rangle)$ inner product space , we know that we can define a norm on $X$ by $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ how can  I prove that $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is [strictly convex normed space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space)?

By using the following definition of strictly convex normed space :
If $x$ does not equal to $0$ and $y$ does not equal to $0$ and $\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ then $y=ax$ where $a>0$

Comment: The parallelogram identity shows that an inner product space is even uniformly convex.

Comment: @DanielFischer A inner product space might not be complete, but every uniformly convex space is complete. Does this mean that an inner product space can be incomplete, but the derived normed space is complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us say that we have two distinct points $x,y$ on the unit sphere. Then

$$\|\tfrac{1}{2}(x+y)\|^2=\tfrac{1}{2}\|x\|^2+\tfrac{1}{2}\|y\|^2-\tfrac{1}{4}\underbrace{\|x-y\|^2}_{>0}< 1.$$

Consequently, $\|x-y\|<2$.

Comment: Is the last line supposed to say $\|x+y\|<2$ rather than $\|x-y\|<2$? (I guess it is just a typo, but I've decided to ask in a comment rather than just edit the answer - just in case I missed something.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak He used essentially the parallelogram identity $||v+w||^2+||v-w||^2=2||v||^2+2||w||^2$ to prove $\frac{1}{2}||x+y||<1$ for $x\neq y$ with $||x||=||y||=1$. Hence the $||x-y||^2$ term on the right hand side and as a consequence $||x-y||<2$.