# Prove norm on any Hilbert space is strictly convex

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I've seen in lecture notes that norm on any Hilbert space is strictly convex means

"$\|x\|=\|y\|=1, \quad\|x+y\|=2 \Rightarrow x=y$"

But why this means strict convexity? I thought strict convexity means 
$\forall x_{1} \neq x_{2} \in H, \forall t \in(0,1) : \quad \|t x_{1}+(1-t) x_{2}\|<t \|f\left(x_{1}\right)\|+(1-t)\| f\left(x_{2}\right)\|$?

It would be best if you can please give a complete proof of why norm on "any" Hilbert space is strictly convex

Comment: Perhaps it would help you to think of strict convexity in terms of an inequality: if $x \neq y$ are two points for which $||x||=1=||y||$, it follows that $$||(x+y)/2||<1$$

Comment: My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3174211/uniformly-convex-implies-strictly-convex/3174549#3174549) may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2133559/how-can-i-prove-that-every-inner-product-space-is-strictly-convex-normed-space

Comment: @avs A helpful link, but not really a duplicate. The asker is more confused about how the (seemingly) weaker form of strict convexity implies the stronger form.